# Nodejs project failed to find ghostscript installed with Chocolatey

Tags: node.js, chocolatey

I am editing a Node.js application which requires Ghostscript. I installed Ghostscript using Chocolatey in admin PowerShell: `choco install ghostscript`. The installation completed successfully and the package is located in C:\ProgramData\chocolatey.chocolatey\Ghostscript.9.55.0.

But when I run the application (locally from VS code), it throws an error `Command failed: gm identify: Failed to find Ghostscript (not installed?).`

Do I need to adjust some path so that Node.js knows where to look for the package?

Answer (score 1):

because `node.js` searching for Ghostscript in `node_modules` folder and it's actually not there.

*now the solution is to install it in node.js via npm*

```
npm i ghostscript4js
```

### Package description: This module binds the Ghostscript C API to bring its power to the Node.JS world

**Read more on its official docs here [ghostscript4js npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ghostscript4js)** Or [Github repository](https://github.com/NickNaso/ghostscript4js)